# How to update any view from python code, before rendering completion, in Odoo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I have a problem with passing value for colors argument in my view element.
So i have my model which has a function to return colors:

```
class MyTask(models.Model):
     _inherit = "project.task"
     is_special=fields.Boolean()     

     @api.model
     def get_colors(self):
          return 'red: is_special == true;'
```

And I also have got my view which looks like this:

```xml
<record id="my_module_timeline" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="model">project.task</field>
<field name="type">timeline</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <timeline date_start="date_start"
            date_stop="date_end"
            default_group_by="project_id"
            event_open_popup="true"
            colors= <-- how can i get the value from my model get_colors() function?
            >
    </timeline>
</field>
```

**colors** argument has to be string, and it cannot be a field of model.
I tried a lot options to get this string from model function, but without good results.

`<timeline>` element is just example it can be also tree, calendar etc.
For tests i got it from:

https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/11.0/web_timeline

It is possible in this way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fields_view_get` method to update the view dynamically from python code (before the view is rendered). This is just an example that I found in Odoo:

```
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = super(MailThread, self).fields_view_get(
        view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu
    )
    if view_type == 'form':
        doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
        for node in doc.xpath("//field[@name='message_ids']"):
            # the 'Log a note' button is employee only
            options = safe_eval(node.get('options', '{}'))
            is_employee = self.env.user.has_group('base.group_user')
            options['display_log_button'] = is_employee
            # save options on the node
            node.set('options', repr(options))
        res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc, encoding='unicode')
    return res
```

Place it in your model. Look for the node with `doc.xpath` and update it with `node.set`